# Not getting Text Area value with file upload JSP and Servet 2.5

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to submit a form with text fields, text area, file field etc in a JSP form. I am using commons file upload for this form.

Here is my JSP form:

```
<form name="add_product_form" id="add_product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Product.Add">
    <div id="form-body">
        <div id="lebel">
            <font color="red">*</font>Product Name:
        </div>
        <div id="field">
            <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="lebel">
             <font color="red">*</font>SKU No:
        </div>
        <div id="field">
            <input type="text" name="sku_no" id="sku_no" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="lebel">
             <font color="red">&nbsp;</font>In Date:
        </div>
        <div id="field">
            <input type="text" name="in_date" id="in_date" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="lebel">
            <font color="red">&nbsp;</font>Upload Image:
        </div>
        <div id="field">
            <input type="file" name="upload_image" id="upload_image" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="lebel">
            <font color="red">&nbsp;</font>Description:
        </div>
        <div id="field">
            <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="lebel">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="button_field">
            <input type="submit" name="add_product_button" id="add_product_button" value="Add  Product">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am getting the value of the text fields using following methods.

```
List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
// Process the uploaded file items
Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

while ( i.hasNext () )
{
    FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
    if ( !fi.isFormField () )
    {
        // Get the uploaded file parameters
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        String value = fi.getString();
        fileName = fi.getName();
        String contentType = fi.getContentType();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
        // Write the file
        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 )
        {
            file = new File( filePath +
            fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        }
        else
        {
            file = new File( filePath +
            fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        }
        fi.write( file ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        String name = fi.getFieldName();
        String value = fi.getString();
        if( name.equals("product_name") )
        {
            productName = value;
        }
        else if( name.equals("sku_no") )
        {
            skuNo = value;
        }
        else if( name.equals("in_date") )
        {
            newDateString = value;
        }
        else if( name.equals("description") )
        {
            productDesc = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting the value of "TextArea" I have used in my form with name "descripton".

Can anyone help me in getting the value of this text area when submitting the form.

Thanks